# Is $C^{p+1}$ everywhere dense in $C^{p}$ with the metric$d(f,g)=\max\{M_0,\cdots,M_k\}, where M_i=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f^{(i)}(x)-g^{(i)}(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

(1)

I'm learning metric space (Mathematical Analysis by Zorich), and I wonder if $C^{p+1}([a,b])$(the set of functions $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R} $ having continuous derivatives up to order $p+1$),is everywhere dense in $C^{p}([a,b])$ with the metric $d(f,g)=\int^b_a|f(x)-g(x)|dx$.

For $p=0$, $\forall f\in C^p([a,b]),\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0,w(f;U^{\delta}(x))<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$,
we can find a function $F_{\delta}(x)=\frac1{2\delta}\int^{x+\delta}_{x-\delta}f(x)dx\in C^{p+1}[a,b]$ , so that $\int^b_a|F_{\delta}(x)-f(x)|dx\leq\int^b_a w(f;U^{\delta}(x)) dx\leq\epsilon$.

As a result, $C^{p+1}$ everywhere dense in $C^{p}$. Is this proposition (as well as the proof) right? Further more, is $C^{p+k}[a,b]$ (or even $C^{\infty}[a,b]$) everywhere dense in $C^p[a,b]$?

(2)

What about with the metric
$$d(f,g)=\max\{M_0,\cdots,M_k\}, where M_i=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f^{(i)}(x)-g^{(i)}(x)|?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any function in $C^{p}[a,b]$ is continuous so it is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials (by Weierstrass Theorem). This proves the result since polynomials are infinitely differentiable and uniform convergence implies convergence in the metric $d$.

If $f$ is $C^{1}$ function then there exist polynomials $p_n$ converging to $f'$ uniformly and the equation $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x} f'(t)dt$ shows that $p_n(0)+\int_0^{x} p_n(t)dt$ converges to $f$ uniformly. Repetition of this argument shows that $C^{p+1}[a,b]$ is dense in $C^{p}[a,b]$ w.r.t. the other two metrics you mentioned.